Rollup failed to resolve import
I'm starting my adventure with windows, before i can build my code in Ubuntu OS.
import {CommonProvider} from '@common/core/common-provider';
return this error,
Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "@common/core/common-provider" from "C:\xampp\htdocs\drive\resources\client\main.tsx".
in the folder no file named main.tsx but common-provider.tsx.
i try to search tsconfig.json to arrangethis,
any help is welcome.
tsconfig.json :
{
"compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": "",
"paths": {
  "@common/*": ["common/resources/client/*"],
  "@app/*": ["resources/client/*"]
},
 *emphasized text*"target": "ESNext",
 "useDefineForClassFields": true,
 "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
 "allowJs": false,
 "skipLibCheck": false,
 "esModuleInterop": false,
 "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
 "strict": true,
 "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
 "module": "ESNext",
 "moduleResolution": "Node",
 "resolveJsonModule": true,
 "isolatedModules": true,
 "noEmit": true,
 "jsx": "react-jsx"
},
"include": ["resources/client", "common/resources/client"],
"references": [{"path": "./tsconfig.node.json"}]
}

